# Android: (CalendarView) Not able to change Month, selected Date

Tags: android, calendar, calendarview

I inflated a simple CalendarView:

```
<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@android:style/Widget.CalendarView"
    android:focusedMonthDateColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
    android:unfocusedMonthDateColor="@color/light_gray"/>
```

On my test device when I try to select any date other than the current date or change the month by scrolling, nothing happens

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you want to achieve,

1. Fire an event when the date changes
2. Fire an event when the month changes

### Capture Data Change Event

The Android's CalenderView provides the function onDateChangeListener. You can use it as follows:

```
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView calendarView, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

            // do something here
        }
    });
```

### Capture Month Change Event

Unfortunately, you cannot achieve this using Android's default CalenderView. However, an alternative customized MaterialCalendarView is available [here](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/) that provides both the date and month change listeners.

The sample code to use the view is as follows:

```
MaterialCalendarView calendarView = new MaterialCalendarView(getActivity());
calendarView.setOnMonthChangedListener(new OnMonthChangedListener() {
 @Override
 public void onMonthChanged(MaterialCalendarView widget, CalendarDay date) {
        // Do something here
        Date selectedDate = date.getDate();
 }
});
```

The date change listener can also be implemented in the similar manner.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to use https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

It is highly customizable CalendarView for android and has a good documentation.
Very easy to use i use it in most of my projects.

Comment: Thanks, but I need Calendar as part of the screen and not a dialog. That's why opted for CalendarView.

Comment: You should assign an onDateChange listener from your calendar view and change than the date on your CalendarView